# Does Django CMS run on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I've seen a few old threads on this topic, but they seemed quite outdated. So, I'm planning a CMS project. The requirements are:

- Use Google App Engine
- Use Python, ideally Django
- Have a CMS, ideally with blogging capabilities
- All used software must be under a very permissive license (BSD/MIT/Apache/etc)

As I'm both a Python and an App Engine newbie, I'd like to know about other people's experience beforehand. Is it possible to run Django CMS on App Engine? Does this work with a Vanilla install?

Answer (score 1):

Django is supported by GAE as you can see here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django. In fact, they even provide the library for you, so that you don't need to include it with your project during deployment. I didn't try Django CMS, but if the requirements are the same than those for Django, it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I had seen that, but as I have very little experience with all the involved components, I hoped to gain some insight into somebody else's experience.